# tensorflow in production

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, data-mining, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow-serving to write a server to consume models in production.
I have a question about consuming the service by clients: does tensorflow-serving support a REST API? Is there is anyway to modify it?

I have checked several github projects: [here](https://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist/tree/master/mnist), [here](https://github.com/Irtza/tensorflow_Server), and [here](https://github.com/benman1/tensorflow_flask).

Comment: Isn't the first link what you want?

Comment: Yes it is very similar, I am asking if the same is provided by google, I like to use the tensor - server . It is ver efficient.

Comment: This is maybe what you are searching for:
https://becominghuman.ai/creating-restful-api-to-tensorflow-models-c5c57b692c10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an answer now for my question.
I will share briefly the main steps / technologies I used to deploy the model in production.

I am using Python programming language.
After training and generating valid models I wrote a restful api using Python programming language and flask.

Using flask you can write a restful api. Three important points:

1- It is very important to give attention to where you will define the model architecture/initialize the parameters/ define the session.
Avoid doing this each time you call the restful api. this will be very expensive.

2- Flask provide a very good mechanism to run servers in production environment.
Read about flask + wcgi 
Avoid runing the server code (the resful api) directly, in this case you will not have direct and full control.

3- Watch the memory and the cpu usage, make sure to limit the maximum number of instances that can run in parallel. Remember these models can take a lot from the memory.

unfortunately, I can not share codes with public. But hopefully my answer can give an idea about how to do it in production.